# using preg_match to detect persian (farsi) characters in string

Tags: php, unicode, preg-match, persian

I am trying to validate form data from server-side.
my interest is that the user just fill the form by Persian characters.

I am using this code:

```
$name=trim($_POST['name']);
$name= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
if (preg_match('/^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$/',str_replace("\\\\","",$name))){$err.= "Please use Persian characters!";}
```

but it is not working!

here is a warning:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offset 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\form.php on line 38
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This 'should' work...

** added a ^ after the opening [ to exclude arabic/farsi characters from the match...

```
if (preg_match('/^[^\x{600}-\x{6FF}]+$/u', str_replace("\\\\","",$name)))
```

Answer (score 11):

http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&number=1024&utf8=0x&addlinks=1&htmlent=1

پژگچ in 600 - 6FF range

fa only:

```
preg_match('/^[پچجحخهعغفقثصضشسیبلاتنمکگوئدذرزطظژؤإأءًٌٍَُِّ\s]+$/u', $input);
```

en , en-num and fa character:

```
 preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9 پچجحخهعغفقثصضشسیبلاتنمکگوئدذرزطظژؤإأءًٌٍَُِّ])+$/u', $input);
```

you can set fa-numbers or arabic ي ك

Answer (score 5):

You should use this:

```
if(preg_match("/^[آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]/", $_POST['name']))
```